# Apk location in New Android Studio

Tags: android, apk, android-studio

I started using new Android Studio and cant find the APK of the application in IDE,where it actually locates?

Comment: If you are using Gradle, then it would be in the build/apk folder.

Comment: doing "find . -name *.apk" in your project directory might help

Comment: It is available in Project source code directory >> Out >> Production >> Project dir >> project.apk

Comment: For official sources add what build system are you using? Path is configured in build config. It has default value.

Comment: For me it was in `app/production/release`

Comment: You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702053/where-is-android-studio-building-my-apk-file/49254232#49254232) for you answer.

Comment: In the latest version Snow Cat the .apk file is found in the 'outputs' folder. A screenshot is in my blog. https://hodentek.blogspot.com/2021/10/locating-apk-file-in-android-studio.html

Answer (score 124, accepted):

To help people who might search for answer to this same question, it is important to know what type of projects you are using in Studio.

**Gradle**

The default project type when creating new project, and the recommended one in general is Gradle.

For a new project called "Foo", the structure under the main folder will be

```
Foo/
    settings.gradle
    Foo/
        build.gradle
        build/
```

Where the internal "Foo" folder is the main module (this structure allows you to create more modules later on in the same structure without changes).

In this setup, the location of the generated APK will be under

```
Foo/Foo/build/apk/...
```

Note that each module can generate its own output, so the true output is more

```
Foo/*/build/apk/...
```

*EDIT*
On the newest version of the Android Studio location path for generated output is

```
Foo/*/build/outputs/apk/...
```

**IntelliJ**

If you are a user of IntelliJ before switching to Studio, and are importing your IntelliJ project directly, then nothing changed. The location of the output will be the same under:

```
out/production/...
```

Note: this is will become deprecated sometimes around 1.0

**Eclipse**

If you are importing Android Eclipse project directly, **do not do this!**
As soon as you have dependencies in your project (jars or Library Projects), this will not work and your project will not be properly setup.
If you have no dependencies, then the apk would be under the same location as you'd find it in Eclipse:

```
bin/...
```

However I cannot stress enough the importance of **not** doing this.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically define which module is your main module and what is the destination (and name) of final project APK file?

Comment: Good answer! This worked for me on Android Studio beta 0.8.2 `Foo/*/build/outputs/apk/...` but for some reason outputs directory is hidden and I can't see it inside Android Studio, any hint?

Comment: To me, this is not true any more. I found the APK under the "intermediates" folder.

Answer (score 81):

I am on **Android Studio 0.6** and the apk was generated in

```
MyApp/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk
```

It included all libraries so I could share it.

---

Update on **Android Studio 0.8.3 Beta**. The apk is now in

```
MyApp/myapp/build/apk/myapp-debug.apk
```

---

Update on **Android Studio 0.8.6 - 2.0**. The apk is now in

```
MyApp/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk
```

Comment: Just want to add that as of 0.8.6 it gets dropped in build/outputs/apk/. A minor difference, but still wanted to update :)

Answer (score 60):

There is really no reason to dig through paths; the IDE hands it to you (at least with version 1.5.1).

In the `Build` menu, select `Build APK`:

[image: Android Studio Build Menu]

A dialog will appear:

[image: Android Studio APK Generated Dialog]

If you are using a newer version of Android Studio, it might look like this:

[image: prompt to locate your APK file]

Clicking the `Show in Explorer` or `locate` link, you will be presented with a file explorer positioned somewhere near wherever Android Studio put the APK file:

[image: File explorer after clicking the link in the APK Generated dialog]

But in AS 3, when you click `locate`, it puts you at the `app` level.  You need to go into the `release` folder to get your `APK` file.

[image: folder structure in AS 3]

[image: folder contents after a build]

Comment: @Dale what does these both apk mean??

Comment: An APK file is the file format used for installing software on the Android operating system

Comment: And yet, in Android Studio 2.2.3, there is no `Build APK` command. (or it is hidden better)

Comment: This is only true for _signed_ apk , i.e.  a realease, the problem is debug builds don't show this prompt and have a different path -> missing feature

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2, I get my APK file from:

```
<myAndroidProject>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 8):

If anyone would be missing his APK and couldn't find it in the locations stated in other answers (I found this question, since I couldn't find it either) it might just be in this folder (mine was)

```
<project folder>/target/classes/<appname>.apk
```

I also had a there this file:

```
<appname>.unaligned.apk
```

I am not perfectly sure, whether the apk is actually the full-blown apk, which should be generated, but I tried it on various devices (not only the target device, but also those which were supporting only the minimum SDK) and it worked.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 8):

It is Project_Location/app/build/outputs/apk for Gradle Project

Answer (score 7):

Find `apk` using below step:-

1. Goto to your project folder.
2. Open project folder.
3. Open `build` folder.
4. Open `output` folder.
5. Open `apk` folder.
6. Now you see your `apk`.

hope it will help some body.

Answer (score 6):

So the apk in Android studio is generated inside `build` folder of **app** module.

Correct path to apk would be `\app\build\outputs\apk`. I am using Android Studio Version 1.4.1. So apk could either be found at `app/build/apk/` or `\app\build\outputs\apk` base on the version of Android studio you are using. Refer the below image

[image: Android studio project structure]

Also find more reference on these links.

1. [Building and Running from Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html)
2. [Studio Project Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Android Studio and gradle. 
It created the build/apk/<.apk> file only when I ran the project. 
Press the following to run your project: Alt+u, u

Android Studio: 0.5.3
Gradle: 0.9.+

Comment: From all the answers, that one solve it correctly. apk was only created when I ran the project. I didn't need to start the emulator. Just pressed the play button to the side of the project name. Is there another way to force Android Studio do create the apk files?

Answer (score 5):

You can find the APK in:

```
YourProject\app\build\outputs\apk
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.apk` file is located at `[your project]\out\production\[your project name]`

Comment: Is this still true now? I do not see an out folder in Android studio project directories anymore. Maybe this is just for projects imported over from Eclipse not ones started in Android Studio.

Comment: @AndrewS - look in your `.classpath` file for the `kind="output"` entry.

Comment: Or in your .iml file for the `BUILD_FOLDER_PATH` configuration option.

Answer (score 3):

In the new Android Studio, the signed apk is placed directly in the folder of module for which the apk is built.

For example:  For a Project ProjectA containing 2 modules Mod1 and Mod2, the apk files will be found in

/path-to-ProjectA/Mod1/Mod1.apk

---

/path-to-ProjectA/Mod2/Mod2.apk

[Image for APK location in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WebQO.jpg)

Comment: How do I know which module is the *main* application module? Is there a possibility (for example, for some script) to exactly define the resulting APK file path and name when everything I know is the root project directory location?

Answer (score 3):

Location of apk in Android Studio:

AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk

Answer (score 3):

As of **version 0.8.6 of Android Studio** generating an APK file (signed and I believe unsigned, too) will be placed inside *ProjectName/device/build/outputs/apk*

For example, I am making something for Google Glass and my signed APK gets dropped in */Users/MyName/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloGlass/glass/build/outputs/apk*

Answer (score 3):

I got the .apk files in 
 parent_folder/out/production/projectname/projectname.apk

Answer (score 2):

Build your project and get the `apk` from `your_project\app\build\apk`

Answer (score 2):

You can find your apk file as follow:

```
yourproject>app>build>output>apk>yourproject.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

> The Android build system is the toolkit you use to build, test, run
>   and package your apps. The build system can run as an integrated tool
>   from the Android Studio menu and independently from the command line.
>   You can use the features of the build system to:

1. **Customize, configure, and extend the build process**.
2. Create ***multiple APKs*** for your app with different features using the
   same project and modules.

The build process involves many tools and processes that generate intermediate files on the way to producing an **`.apk`**. If you are developing in Android Studio, the complete build process is done every time you run the Gradle build task for your project or modules.

The build process is very flexible so it's useful, however, to understand what is happening under the hood since much of the build process is configurable and extensible. The following diagram depicts the different tools and processes that are involved in a build:

### Build a release version

You can now use the Build menu options to build the release version of your application for distribution.

The build generates an APK for each build variant: the **`app/build/apk/`** (or **`app/build/outputs/apk`**) directory contains packages named app--.apk; for example, app-full-release.apk and app-demo-debug.apk.

[image]

**Build output**

*The build generates an APK for each build variant in the `app/build folder`: the **`app/build/outputs/apk/ directory`** contains packages named app--.apk; for example, **app-full-release.apk and app-demo-debug.apk**.*

Courtesy goes to  **[Build System Overview](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)**

Answer (score 2):

I am using Android Studio 3.0 canary 6.

To build apk,

Click to `Build->Build APK(s)`.

After your apk is build, Go to:

```
C:\Users\your-pc-name\AndroidStudioProjects\your-app-name\app\build\outputs\apk\debug
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have imported a Project from Eclipse and are using the new Android Studio
The directory

```
/bin
```

does exist (there maybe old binaries in here) **however** with the latest Android Studio update the actual **current apk** is stored in

```
/out/production
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your module gradle file. Its not there in default project. Then u will surely find the APK in /build/outputs/apk/

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. open Event Log
2. find line: Module 'app': *locate* or analyze the APK.
3. click on locate link to open folder with apk file!

After all: "All built APKs are saved in project-name/module-name/build/outputs/apk/ [Build your project LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#reference)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you can´t see the app-debug.apk in your debug folder, you have to click on BUILD --> Rebuild Project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

To create apk in android studio,go to build menu->build bundles/apk->build apk

it will make the apk file of your project.After this the apk will be available in your

project directory->app->build->outputs->apk->debug->app-debug.apk

Answer (score 1):

Click on Build-Build Bundles/Apks-Build Apk.

A notification will which shows app location when you click on 'locate' on the notification.

If you have already done creating apk, goto : C:\Users\\AndroidStudioProjects\\app\build\outputs\apk\debug

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle look here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html.
"*For example: Java plugin will use those dirs in calculating class paths and for jarring the content; IDEA and Eclipse plugins will put those folders on relevant classpath.*"

So its depend on plugin build in configs unless you don't define them explicit in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Click the little gear icon in the project view and make sure "show excluded files" is checked.  Otherwise, the IDE will hide `output` and several other important directories under `$project/$module/build/`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all above all answers are right you can find the apk through the path in android studio but there is exceptions you can't find the **build/output**
folder some times if you can't see it just go to

app--> `app.iml`  file and find below line in it :-

```
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/outputs" />
```

--> after **removing**  this line you can see the output folder its just the adding more information to above answers as per my experience :)

THANKS!~!

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 2.0

```
C:\Users\UserName\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppName\app\build\outputs\apk
```

Here 
    UserName is your computer user name and 
    MyAppName is your android app name

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio 3.0 / Gradle Build Tools 3.0.0, APK artifacts can now be found in `foo/bar/build/outputs/apk/flavorName/buildType` with respect to your project name, `foo`, and your module name, `bar`. There is now a directory for each `apk` file sorted organized first by flavor (with respect to flavor dimensions) and then by build type.

Answer (score 0):

First the apk has to be built.
In Android Studio, Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s).
Then find the apk in C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\outputs\apk\debug.