# Android studio generates zip file instead of apk

Tags: android

I just finished compilling my android application using android studio. But the output was a zip file, not an apk file as i expected. Will the zip file work on android device just like an  apk file? Or is there something that i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check on your project's location on your computer for

> "out/production/..."

IntelliJ stores the apk there.

You can find more answers to your question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio)

Comment: thks Mood. My android studio  saved the apk file in build/apk/<appname>-debug-unaligned.apk. Why is the debug-unalighed appended despite the fact that i signed the app before compilling