# Building Android apps with Gradle -- empty bin directory

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio, android-testing

I am following the Android Developer's [Activity Testing Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html), however, since I am using Android Studio I am following the tutorial using the section [For Users Not Developing in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html#EditorCommandLine) (located in the tutorial's appendix).

In step 5, it states "Build the sample application.". I am using Gradle as my build tool and building as follows:

```
cd Spinner
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This results in "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", however the bin directory is empty (does not contain "SpinnerActivity-debug.apk" as required/expected by the tutorial).

How do I build using Gradle such that the bin directory contains the file "SpinnerActivity-debug.apk"?

Comment: Check under app/build/outputs/apk folder

Comment: Also, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16620366/2191256

Comment: Gradle does not use the `bin/` directory. That is something that Eclipse and Ant used.