# Android App Sharing

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for someone who lives pretty far away from me. I'm using android studio. My boss wants to try the app on their phone however My boss doesn't have android studio and doesn't know how to use git. How can I get the app on their phone? Is there a way to access the app files so that they can be place on the phone easily?

Comment: You can export the .apk and place it on any cloud-storage facility (Google Drive, Dropbox...)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Build your App](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html) in Android Studio. To be 100% sure, run your app on your test device
2. Locate your APK. It should be at [MyApp/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162674/225503)
3. Send the APK using email, or better, upload the APK to Dropbox, your web server and email the link

Answer (score 0):

Export your .apk file and send it to him. All he needs to do is find the file and hit it. Then he can install it.