# Where is .apk file for android studio 2.1? like in eclipse its in "bin" folder

Tags: android

I am new in android studio, till now I am work on eclipse but now move to android studio, so Where is .apk file for android studio 2.1? like in eclipse its in "bin" folder.

there are 2 app-debug-unaligned.apk & app-debug.apk file. But when I take that APK file in my mobile for running test app. than after installed its crash

so basically i want to generate .apk file for external use. like when i am using eclipse, apk file in bin folder . when i take that apk file to my mobile that perfectly working

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio

Comment: @JnT check the image in answers

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37589133/1537419

Answer (score 1):

Hope you would find this helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find your apk here

```
YourProject/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: app-debug.apk & app-debug-unaligned.apk both are generated in apk folder but when I take it on my mobile its not working perfectly.

Comment: simpley rename app-debug.apk to your application name and try to install on device it amy help you

Answer (score 0):

Find your apk @,

```
YOUR_APP_PATH\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
YOUR_APP_PATH\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
```

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

Open Project
1. Click on Your App
2. Click on Build 
3. Click on outputs
4. Click on apk
5. Here You get app-debug.apk  which is apk file

Comment: there are 2 app-debug-unaligned.apk & app-debug.apk  file. But when I take that APK file in my mobile for running test app. than after installed its crash.

Comment: app-debug.apk is the apk

Comment: so basically i want to generate .apk file for external use. like when i am using eclipse, apk file in bin folder . when i take that apk file to my mobile that perfectly working

Comment: have you tested your build on any emulator for errors?

Comment: Its unfortunately stop alert box is display when  
app-debug.apk  is installed in mobile

Comment: have you checked targetSdkVersion

Answer (score 0):

You can find it from android studio by changing the view structure to project
[view the picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc7Rg.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your answer for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration,When you are generating signed apk by default your apk will fall under the below mentioned folder.

**Your_Projects_Folder/app/app-release.apk**

All your debug apk file will generate in build folder like Sathis Kumar J metioned,[Unsigned Debug Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588939/1537419)